# I keep getting error when I'm creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting error when I'm creating trigger.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER ORDER_BILL_TRIG AFTER
    INSERT ON ORDER_BILL
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    [REFERENCING NEW AS N]
    UPDATE ORDER_BILL
    SET ORDER_BILL = QUANTITY * (SELECT FOOD_PRICE FROM FOOD WHERE
    FOOD_PRICE = N.FOOD_NUM) WHERE N.FOOD_NUM = FOOD_NUM;
```

**Error is:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DB2SQL [REFERENCING NEW AS N] UPDATE ORDER_BILL
>   SET ORDER_BILL = QUANTITY * (SEL' at line 3

I don't have idea how to fix it

Comment: Mysql does not have mode or [Referncing. You should review dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html and dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html (a trigger is a stored program) BUT mysql won't allow you to action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger. MYSQL WILL allow you to set the NEW. value of a column in a before trigger (which I suspect is what you want)

Comment: "MODE DB2SQL", have you just copied the code from another database (using DB2)? Wouldn't it be a good start to read the documentation for creating triggers on MySql first?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code in MySQL -

```
CREATE TRIGGER ORDER_BILL_TRIG
AFTER
INSERT ON ORDER_BILL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE ORDER_BILL
  SET ORDER_BILL = QUANTITY * (SELECT FOOD_PRICE
                               FROM FOOD
                               WHERE FOOD_PRICE = NEW.FOOD_NUM)
  WHERE NEW.FOOD_NUM = FOOD_NUM;
END;
```

Comment: mysql won't allow you to action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger

Answer (score 0):

As commented by P.Salmon and Joakim Danielson, there are various problem with the code of your trigger:

- `REFERENCING` is not supported in MySQL
- an `AFTER` trigger cannot action the table it is bound to
- `mode DB2SQL` does not make sense in MySQL

My understanding of your use case is that, everytime a new bill is inserted, you want to automatically set the bill price from the quantity that was billed and the price of the product (which can be found in the `food` table.

A solution would be to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to set the bill price before the insert is executed.

Here is a **[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/inbFQo5RNSFUbj2uuEKZ3p/0)** and a step-by-step explanation.

1) Consider the following table structure for tables `order_bill` and `food`:

```
create table order_bill (
    bill_num int primary key auto_increment,
    food_num int,
    quantity int,
    bill_price int
);

create table food (
    food_num int primary key,
    food_price int
);
```

2) The `food` table contains one record, that defines a price of 10 for `food_num` 1:

```
| food_num | food_price |
| -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | 10         |
```

3) We define the trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_bill_trig
    BEFORE INSERT ON order_bill
    FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.bill_price = (
        SELECT food_price 
        FROM food
        WHERE food_num = NEW.food_num
    ) * NEW.quantity
;
```

4) Now let's insert a new record in the `order_bill` table, with a quantity of 10 of `food_num` 1:

```
INSERT INTO order_bill(food_num, quantity) VALUES(1, 5);
```

5) The trigger fires and sets the `bill_price` to (`5 * 10 = 50`). The content of the `order_bill` is now as follows:

```
| bill_num | food_num | quantity | bill_price |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | 1        | 5        | 50         |
```